# extract COVID data across sub-regions of Asia and the Pacific

Tags: manipulate, curated-data

The following code extracts COVID data of Germany and gives the time series of confirmed cases, deaths and recoveries:

```
ResourceRemove[ResourceObject["Epidemic Data for Novel Coronavirus COVID-19"]];
covid = ResourceData["Epidemic Data for Novel Coronavirus COVID-19", "WorldCountries"];
casesGer =covid[Select[MatchQ[Entity["Country", "Germany"], #Country] &]][All, {#ConfirmedCases, #RecoveredCases, #Deaths} &][Total];
DateListLogPlot[casesGer, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

I wanted to apply the above code for the following sub-regions:

```
cAsia = {"Kazakhstan", "Kyrgyzstan", "Tajikistan", "Turkmenistan", 
   "Uzbekistan"};
eAsia = {"China", "Japan", "Mongolia", "NorthKorea", "SouthKorea"};
seAsia = {"Brunei", "Cambodia", "Indonesia", "Laos", "Malaysia", 
   "Myanmar", "Philippines", "Singapore", "Thailand", "EastTimor", 
   "Vietnam"};
sAsia = {"Afghanistan", "Bangladesh", "Bhutan", "India", "Iran", 
   "Maldives", "Nepal", "Pakistan", "SriLanka"};
wAsia = {"Armenia", "Azerbaijan", "Bahrain", "Cyprus", "Georgia", 
   "Iraq", "Israel", "Jordan", "Kuwait", "Lebanon", "Oman", "Qatar", 
   "SaudiArabia", "Syria", "Turkey", "UnitedArabEmirates", "WestBank",
    "GazaStrip", "Yemen"};
```

and produce a single time-series graph of `confirmed cases, deaths, recoveries` for each sub-region above. Using `Manipulate` is preferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this kind of presentation which data and graphic are static (doesn't change), I suggest `TabView`:

[image]

Initials:

```
covid = ResourceData["Epidemic Data for Novel Coronavirus COVID-19", 
   "WorldCountries"];

cAsia = {"Kazakhstan", "Kyrgyzstan", "Tajikistan", "Turkmenistan", "Uzbekistan"};
eAsia = {"China", "Japan", "Mongolia", "NorthKorea", "SouthKorea"};
seAsia = {"Brunei", "Cambodia", "Indonesia", "Laos", "Malaysia", "Myanmar", "Philippines", "Singapore", "Thailand", "EastTimor", "Vietnam"};
sAsia = {"Afghanistan", "Bangladesh", "Bhutan", "India", "Iran", "Maldives", "Nepal", "Pakistan", "SriLanka"};
wAsia = {"Armenia", "Azerbaijan", "Bahrain", "Cyprus", "Georgia", "Iraq", "Israel", "Jordan", "Kuwait", "Lebanon", "Oman", "Qatar", "SaudiArabia", "Syria", "Turkey", "UnitedArabEmirates", "WestBank", "GazaStrip", "Yemen"};
```

Code:

```
ClearAll[fn, groups, data];
fn[countries_List] := 
 With[{result = 
    Transpose@Normal@covid[
        Select[MemberQ[countries, #Country] &], {2, 4, 5, 6}][All, 
       Values]
 }, 
  Column[{GraphicsRow[
     MapIndexed[
      DateListLogPlot[#1, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", 
        PlotLabel -> {"Confirmed Cases", "Recovered Cases", "Deaths"}[[First@#2]]] &, result[[2 ;;]]]
 ], 
    LineLegend[ColorData[97, "ColorList"], 
     Intersection[countries, First@result], LegendLayout -> "Row"], 
    Row[{Text@"Missing: ", Complement[countries, First@result]}]}]]

groups = {"cAsia", "eAsia", "seAsia", "sAsia", "wAsia"};
data = AssociationThread[groups, 
   MapAt[Entity["Country", #] &, {cAsia, eAsia, seAsia, sAsia, 
     wAsia}, {All, All}]];

TabView[fn /@ data]
```

### Update - Population-scaled

For dividing cases by population, we could use a fixed number to divide, or use a model that reflects the real-world data. This solution uses `Extrapolation` of the data extracted through `CountryData`. It's not accurate but is better than a fixed number. You can change it by redefining the `populations` variable (should be an `Association` which connects every country as `Entity` to a function that gets time as input and outputs the population at that time).

1- We extract the `population` of all the countries that exist in the list from 2015 to 2021 (data for `GazaStrip` and `WestBank` was missing for both `Covid-cases` and `Population`):

```
populationsRaw = 
  Map[# -> CountryData[#, {"Population", {2015, 2021}}] &, 
   Entity["Country", #] & /@ 
    Flatten[{cAsia, eAsia, seAsia, sAsia, wAsia}]];
```

2- Apply `Association` and drop `GazaStrip` and `WestBank`, then map `Interpolation`:

```
populations = 
  Interpolation /@ 
   KeyDrop[Association@
     populationsRaw, {Entity["Country", "GazaStrip"], 
     Entity["Country", "WestBank"]}];
```

3- Now define a function in which will be applied to `TimeSeries` and give us the desired output:

```
dividePopulation[row_] := 
 Quiet[With[{popFn = populations[First@row]}, 
   MapAt[TimeSeriesMapThread[#2/popFn[#1] &, QuantityMagnitude@#] &, 
    row, {{2}, {3}, {4}}]], {InterpolatingFunction::dmval}]
```

4- The rest is the same, only map the defined function to each row:

```
fnPopulationScaled[countries_List] := 
 With[{result = 
    Transpose[
     dividePopulation /@ 
      Normal@covid[
         Select[MemberQ[countries, #Country] &], {2, 4, 5, 6}][All, 
        Values]]}, 
  Column[{GraphicsRow[
     MapIndexed[
      DateListLogPlot[#1, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", 
        PlotLabel -> {"Confirmed Cases", "Recovered Cases", 
           "Deaths"}[[First@#2]]] &, result[[2 ;;]]]], 
    LineLegend[ColorData[97, "ColorList"], 
     Intersection[countries, First@result], LegendLayout -> "Row"], 
    Row[{Text@"Missing: ", Complement[countries, First@result]}]}]]

groups = {"cAsia", "eAsia", "seAsia", "sAsia", "wAsia"};
data = AssociationThread[groups, 
   MapAt[Entity["Country", #] &, {cAsia, eAsia, seAsia, sAsia, 
     wAsia}, {All, All}]];

TabView[fnPopulationScaled /@ data]
```

Result:

[image]

#### Update 2 - sub-regions

The only difference with first update is replacing `DateListLogPlot[TimeSeriesThread[Total, #1] ...` in `fnPopulationScaled` with `DateListLogPlot[#1 ...`:

Result:

[image]

Comment: It is a nice presentation, and I did not know `TabView` (thanks for this). One more request from you: Currently, your code uses `Cumulative Numbers`. Actually, I just realized that `Population-scaled cumulative numbers` will be useful for country-comparison or region comparison. Can you scale the currently running code with country population? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @TugrulTemel Do you mean each category gets divided by population?

Comment: Yes, the division of each category to population will allow for the comparison of countries across categories.

Comment: Very very clear explanation and thanks for the answer. Excellent...

Comment: I am sorry to bother you again. I have one more request. In the graph just before "Update - population-scaled), we have sub-regional graphs of individual countries. Would it possible to do the same graph for `cumulative sub-regions"? Since we have 5 sub-regions, each graph for each COVID compartment will have only 5 cumulative time series. I hope this explanation is clear.

Comment: @TugrulTemel post updated.